# I'm trying to loop through only parts of an array in java looking for a match

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm new to here and java, no it's not home work, I'm too old for that.
I have an array of doubles,43 rows and 8 columns. I'm trying to find the index of col[1] with an input.
I have figured that out , the problem is there are repeats in col[1] depending on the value in col[0]
so I want to just loop thought say row 11 to row 20 
this is what I'm trying, it just loops to the end

```
 for(int y =15; y<=20;y++) {
    if (td2.Td2[y][1]== P);{
        txtTd2.setText(String.valueOf(td2.Td2[y][4])+ "  "+ y);

        }
    }
```

this is a part of the array , col[0] are diameters, <=1.50, >1.50 <=2.80 etc that's why I'm trying to loop on between certain rows

```
   public class Td2 {

  double Td2[][];{

  Td2 = new double [44][44];

   Td2[0][0]=   1.50    ;   Td2[0   ][1]=   0.20    ;   Td2[0   ][2]=   0.025   ;   
   Td2[1][0]=   1.50    ;   Td2[1   ][1]=   0.25    ;   Td2[1   ][2]=   0.028   ;   
   Td2[2][0]=   1.50    ;   Td2[2   ][1]=   0.35    ;   Td2[2   ][2]=   0.032   ;   
   Td2[3][0]=   1.50    ;   Td2[3   ][1]=   0.40    ;   Td2[3   ][2]=   0.034   ;   
   Td2[4][0]=   1.50    ;   Td2[4   ][1]=   0.45    ;   Td2[4   ][2]=   0.036   ;   
   Td2[5][0]=   2.80    ;   Td2[5   ][1]=   0.35    ;   Td2[5   ][2]=   0.034   ;   
   Td2[6][0]=   2.80    ;   Td2[6   ][1]=   0.50    ;   Td2[6   ][2]=   0.038   ;   
   Td2[7][0]=   2.80    ;   Td2[7   ][1]=   0.60    ;   Td2[7   ][2]=   0.042   ;   
   Td2[8][0]=   2.80    ;   Td2[8   ][1]=   0.70    ;   Td2[8   ][2]=   0.045   ;   
   Td2[9][0]=   2.80    ;   Td2[9   ][1]=   0.75    ;   Td2[9   ][2]=   0.045   ;   
   Td2[1][0]=   2.80    ;   Td2[10  ][1]=   0.80    ;   Td2[10  ][2]=   0.048   ;   
   Td2[11][0]=  5.60    ;   Td2[11  ][1]=   0.75    ;   Td2[11  ][2]=   0.050   ;   
   Td2[12][0]=  5.60    ;   Td2[12  ][1]=   1.00    ;   Td2[12  ][2]=   0.056   ;   
   Td2[13][0]=  5.60    ;   Td2[13  ][1]=   1.25    ;   Td2[13  ][2]=   0.060   ;   
   Td2[14][0]=  5.60    ;   Td2[14  ][1]=   1.50    ;   Td2[14  ][2]=   0.067   ;   
   Td2[15][0]=  11.20   ;   Td2[15  ][1]=   1.00    ;   Td2[15  ][2]=   0.060;
```

Thanks Steve

Comment: "`if (td2.Td2[y][1]== P);{`" remove that semicolon.

Comment: Thanks, I'd managed to figure it out.It's the little things